# Can I use more than one list view in resource layout file?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I use more than one `ListView` in a layout, because my list adapter is considering the `ListView` with id "list", how to set the adapters for the remaining list views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with a ListActivity. You can do it with your own Activity subclass, but you have to be a little careful about defining the heights for vertically stacked ListViews. One way to do it is to put them in a LinearLayout, set the layout_height of each to 0px, and set the layout_weight of them to non-zero numbers in proportion to how much space you want each to take up. (For equal-height lists, for example, set the layout_weight of each to 1.)